# Setup Mock object method for varying inputs and outputs, warns: access to modified closure

Tags: c#, moq

I want to set up a mock object with a method that should return something different for each input.  When I tried something like the code given below I got a warning about access to modified closure (i.e., the access to `i`).  How do I properly setup the mock object's `FooMethod(i)` to return `i*3`?

```
var ret = new Mock<FooClass>();

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    var bar = i*3;
    ret.Setup(x => x.FooMethod(i)).Returns(bar);
}
```

Comment: Assign `i` to another variable inside the loop before calling `ret.Setup`. This makes the lambda catch this local variable at every loop. Otherwsie it will catch `i` only once. See: [Closing over the loop variable considered harmful](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olivier already said it in a comment. Because of the closure semantics for the `for` variable, what Moq sees with your code is really:

```
ret.Setup(x => x.FooMethod(10)).Returns(0);
ret.Setup(x => x.FooMethod(10)).Returns(3);
ret.Setup(x => x.FooMethod(10)).Returns(6);
ret.Setup(x => x.FooMethod(10)).Returns(9);
ret.Setup(x => x.FooMethod(10)).Returns(12);
ret.Setup(x => x.FooMethod(10)).Returns(15);
ret.Setup(x => x.FooMethod(10)).Returns(18);
ret.Setup(x => x.FooMethod(10)).Returns(21);
ret.Setup(x => x.FooMethod(10)).Returns(24);
ret.Setup(x => x.FooMethod(10)).Returns(27);
```

This is not what you want, of course. (Moq will only be set up for the value `10`, and with that it will use the latest `Setup`, hence return `27`.)

Do not close over (capture) the `for` variable. One fix is:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var iCopy = i;
    ret.Setup(x => x.FooMethod(iCopy)).Returns(3 * iCopy);
}
```

In newer versions of C#, a `foreach` loop is different. Therefore, this works:

```
foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, 10)) {
    ret.Setup(x => x.FooMethod(i)).Returns(3 * i);
}
```

Moq offers another method where you do not need a loop. It is like this:

```
ret.Setup(x => x.FooMethod(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns((int i) => 3 * i);
```

Of course this sets up for *all* `i`. If you do not want that, you can change to:

```
ret.Setup(x => x.FooMethod(It.Is((int i) => 0 <= i && i < 10))).Returns((int i) => 3 * i);
```